# Python np.busday_count with datetime64[ns] as input

Tags: python, numpy

I have a column from a pandas Dataframe that I want to use as input for `np.busday_count`:

```
np.busday_count(df['date_from'].tolist(), df['date_to_plus_one'].tolist(), weekmask='1000000')
```

I have always use `.tolist()` but since one of the last updates this results in an error:

```
> TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from
> dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

The column `df['date_from']`is of type `dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

Any tips or solution for this?

Comment: Some further searching gave me the following results: change `.tolist()` to `.values.astype('datetime64[D]')`

Answer (score 2):

try Using

```
df['date_from'].date()
```

The column df['date_from'] with datatype dtype: datetime64[ns] contains data like
2018-04-06 00:00:00 its a timestamp

But np.busyday_count takes datetime.date as input  like "2018-04-06"

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does that code do, and why should one use it?

Comment: It removes the hh:mm:ss fields from the date variable to become only yyyy:mm:dd

Comment: When you use np.busdays_count(), you need to remove that part before (pre-processing)